# why vscode automatically get python version 3.7.3 instead of 3.10.4?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-python

I uninstall python 3.7.3 64-bit and installed python 3.10.4 64-bit on windows. but every time I launch vscode it automatically gets the 3.7.3 version even after I uninstall it. and it shows python 3.7.3 global. after uninstalling 3.7.3 from the control panel it still works in vscode I don't know why?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWh5R.jpg)

Comment: Check your PATH system environment variable. Probably there's path to old python folder set

Comment: can you tell me about path system environment and why 3.7.3 still work in vscode because i uninstall it from control pannel.

Comment: If you're referring to the interpreter you can set the default interpreter path in the user settings: user settings > extensions > python > default interpreter

Comment: As shown in the interface, select the first one to modify the python version in vscode.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly find path of python310.exe (name can be different) it is in Python3.10 folder after that go  VsCode . Click Settings Choose User > Extensions>Python > Python Path  . Remember the path is not complete. So, add “\python.exe” in the end.

Comment: ok now vscode using 3.10 but how to uninstall 3.7 in vscode ? I don't want 3.7 anymore. and what is this 3.7.3 global you can see it in the pic I uploaded.

Comment: go to command palette and wrote Python: Clear Workspace Interpreter Setting  
  Python: Reset Stored Info for Untrusted Interpreters

Comment: user settings: user settings > extensions > python > default interprete, at the end it is \pythonw.exe.